# connect to DB with java without external jar - is there such a thing?

Tags: java, jdbc

i'm connecting to a database with java with the following code:

```
 Class.forName(some driver name);
```

now, in order for it to run i have to include the relevant jar to the build path.
my question is, is there a driver (maybe built in the sdk/jre) that does not require including a jar?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only JDBC driver supplied built-in to the Oracle Java 6 JRE is the [JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html). Its use is not recommended, however.

For any other DBMS, you need a proper JDBC driver JAR.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to connect with out any driver because driver work as a bridge to connect our application with database servers

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: include connector jar in your jar, unpack it somewhere in runtime and use `URLClassLoader` to load driver.

Example of completely abstract invocation of MSSQL driver:

```
URLClassLoader cl = ...; // create and initialize URLClassLoader
Class c = cl.loadClass("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource").newInstance().getClass();
c.getMethod("setUser", String.class).invoke(o, connectionParameters.user);
c.getMethod("setPassword", String.class).invoke(o, connectionParameters.password);
c.getMethod("setServerName", String.class).invoke(o, connectionParameters.serverName);
c.getMethod("setDatabaseName", String.class).invoke(o, connectionParameters.databaseName);
return (Connection) c.getMethod("getConnection").invoke(o);
```

It uses MS-driver-specific methods, but not requires driver to be on your classpath.